# How many tags needed to earn the Generalist badge?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, generalist-badge

Neither at `stackoverflow.com` nor at `serverfault.com` nobody has ever earned the 
*Generalist* badge.

How many different tags do I have to be active in to earn the Generalist badge?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

now implemented! see description for how it works.

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.

for more detail:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/

Comment: What does "15 total score" mean? 15 upvotes? 15 reputation points?

Comment: ::snort:: I note that *everyone* who got it in the initial awarding pass has at least 10k rep...well one exception on SU with 7k.

Comment: Yayyyy! got the Generalist badge!

Comment: @Questions, score generally means upvotes - downvotes, I think.

Comment: <me> off to answer a bunch of beginner, subjective questions about best-practices ... :)

Comment: Yeah, and I suddenly remembered that I have a lot of wisdom to dispense in the .NET tag. I mean, I spent an entire afternoon trying to install the .NET runtime once, that has to count for something, right?

Answer (score 11):

I think that badge might need to be promoted to gold, or its threshold lowered. If it goes gold, then a silver badge could be created with a lower threshold and called something like "Versatile".

Comment: Not Implemented

Comment: See also this question which is tagged "status-planned" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/suggested-implementation-for-generalist-badge

Answer (score 2):

I think an issue with implementing the generalist badge is determining what is general. The simple idea of earning it for earning the tag badge in multiple badges I think has a flaw because so many of the badges are related. If you earn the c# badge, it doesn't really make you a generalist to earn the .net badge. I would argue it wouldn't even be much of a generalist if you also earned the VB badge, there's just so much overlap. I really like the concept, but I'm really not sure how it could be quantified.

Answer (score 1):

It think it should be possible to cluster the tags so that concepts such as .NET and the CLR various languages etc end up together. I could see similar clusters appearing for databases, algorithms and other languages. The badge could then be implemented by saying something like 'you must answer 5 questions with at least 5 upvotes from 3 or more subject areas'.

How does the tag cloud currently work? Does it look at groups of tags?

Comment: Hard to maintain, though - since tags are user-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could be awarded if you get two of the "tag" badges? (The "Earned 400 upvotes for answers in the .net tag" ones)

Comment: The problem with that *specific* scenario is that there is a *lot* of crossover in .NET; for example, anyone with C# pretty much has .NET; likewise, Jon was very amused when he got his VB silver... as someone who occasionally prods VB with a long barge pole called Reflector ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [suggested implementation for Generalist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/suggested-implementation-for-generalist-badge) for an initiative to get this in place.

Answer (score 0):

I do like the site that tells you your progress towards generalist on any of the stackexchange sites (even if it does have a bug in not counting tags that you have scored exactly 15 on as counting towards generalist).

http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/stackapps/badge