# I'm 10K now at SO, what's the next thing to do?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I don't really know what's my 10K rep worth. Well, I can see deleted posts(Q&A), so what? Should I be excited? If this were like online games and I did got a promising level up, what shall I do next?

Simple, but I'm honestly serious with my words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you notice the [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/) menu? There's a fairly extensive list of 10k tools in [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users/4576#4576), but if you're already at 10k you should probably just poke around for yourself; if you enjoy moderating you'll probably spend quite a lot of time in there. I personally use the following a lot, but which things you use will depend on what you like doing:

- [New posts by new users](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-user-posts) (they tend to format things poorly)
- [Newly created tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-tags) (look for potential synonyms or misspellings)
- [Highest voted questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) (not really for moderation, just because they tend to be interesting)
- [Posts with close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days) (to add a vote if a post should be closed)
- [Posts with delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) (you can vote to delete posts now that you're at 10k, although I almost never end up doing so)
- [Posts with spam/offensive flags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) (posts with six flags are automatically deleted, so similar to close votes you can add your own flag if you agree)

Comment: Thank you for this. Now I got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats on hitting 10k rep

See:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/

[The meaning of reputation after 10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/the-meaning-of-reputation-after-10k)

[How to behave now I've got the 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20812/how-to-behave-now-ive-got-the-10k)

[Has anyone out there tried to stop gaining rep so as to not surpass 10k?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49822/has-anyone-out-there-tried-to-stop-gaining-rep-so-as-to-not-surpass-10k)

and

[What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users)

Comment: wow! if that makes everyone happy, why not? ^_^ thanks for the Congrats. I honestly don't know what I can do. I'll be glad if I could do more to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that you've no milestones left to achieve sans first page and Jon Skeet, try to get yourself listed in the all time top users in your favorite tags, jquery and javascript. That's what I did - and I'm still trying to become the first one to bag a Silver badge in flex tag :)

Comment: wow cool! nice encouragement. +1