# New badge idea: Versatile (related to Stack Flair)

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Suggestion to have a **Versatile** badge for those who have good rep in multiple SE sites.

This is to recognize users active across sites - similar to the combined flair but a badge to go along with it.

This could be 3 tier

Bronze  > 200 in at least 7 sites (or some similar threshold)

Silver > 1000 in 10 sites

Gold > 3000 in 10 sites

The badge would be awarded once per site, so if you qualify for Bronze you would get 7 badges at one shot. That might not be a good idea though, I admit.

Any thoughts?

**Update**

The [community at english.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/superlative-version-or-synonym-of-versatile) have suggested the following titles

swiss-army knife, polymath, sage, Da Vinci, homo universalis, protean (Gold), multifaceted, all-rounder.

Though [polymath has already been discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12603/badge-suggestion-polymath-gold-version-of-generalist) earlier for Generalist

Answer (score 2):

If the badge is cross site, it should be awarded to the area51 account.

Comment: Even if they've never used Area51?