# Badge suggestion for multi-site Mortarboard

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, badge-request

#### Description

A badge that would be awarded for gaining >= 200 reputation in a single day on multiple (2) sites across the network.

#### Motivation

I think there are many people that are specialists in their field, but very few are generalists across sites on this network. This may be limited to certain users<sup>*</sup> or events<sup>**</sup>.

<sub><sup>*</sup> This is okay as there are many badges that are typically awarded to a select few high-rep users ([Epic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary) - only users who provide valuable content on a continuous basis), or moderators ([Constable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/constable) or [Sheriff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/208/sheriff));

<sup>**</sup> This is okay as some badges are only associated with events (like Precognitive, or Beta) or when there are major release notes requesting user feedback (like the new [the new user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450/168244) or the [top bar release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420/168244) where some users may find multiple bugs or valuable feedback).</sub>

This proposal should encourage the desired behaviour on sites as it is associated with valuable content on a per-site basis.

#### Considerations

- Silver badge

  [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard) is awarded to an individual gaining (first) 200 reputation on any site. While this might be a feat for some, doing the same on two different sites is not something people do often... I think.
- Awarded multiple times to the user on *both* sites. So, scoring >= 200 reputation on site X and >= 200 reputation on site Y will earn you this badge on X *and* Y.
- Bounties are excluded from this badge... maybe.

#### Names

Some suggestions with an informal mention of the motivation:

- Medium (as in a "go-between")
- Juggler (an individual keeping multiple things in the air at once)
- Trapeze (artists flying around between things)

#### Requests

I don't have the power to gauge how likely this badge could be awarded across multiple sites, as [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) only allows searches by site, not across multiple sites. As such, an answer indicating statistics in that regard would also be helpful.

I'm not referring to [Stackathlon](https://stackapps.com/q/885/27724), as this is specific to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and [Super User](http://superuser.com). And, even though there are other groupings mentioned, it is very specific to the grouping, excluding certain users in general.

---

Related content:

- [Badge for participation in multiple Stack Exchange networks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131348/168244)
- [Stack Exchange badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75257/168244)
- [New Badge Proposal: Renaissance Man](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92138/168244)
- [New badge idea: Versatile (related to Stack Flair)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72507/168244)

Answer (score 7):

I like the idea. I'll suggest that the different levels of the badge (bronze, silver, gold) be awarded not by the number of times something like this is achieved, but by the number of sites this is achieved on.

Example:

- [Mortarboard: One site]
- Medium: Two sites.
- Juggler: Five sites.
- Trapeze: Ten sites.

It's doubtful that people could go much higher than ten. Even that would be pretty hard.

An additional option (to reward extreme feats multiple times) would be to have Trapeze be the only badge which can be awarded multiple times, just like Socratic can be earned multiple times (while Curious and Inquisitive are one-time-only badges).

I also think it should be possible to get all three badges on one day, just as you can get Popular Question, Notable Question, and Famous Question (and their answer equivalents, and some other badges) all on one post.

---

Assorted Musings:

- An offshoot of this would be to have similar badges, but for all-time rep. Bronze would be 1k on multiple sites, silver would be 1k on five sites, gold would be on ten sites, etc. Perhaps 1k is too low (?).

Comment: Are you suggesting Trapeze = 200+ reputation on 10 sites in *one* day? That would be similar (somewhat) to [New Badge Proposal: Renaissance Man](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92138/168244)...

Comment: @Werner I am, believe it or not. It would be incredibly hard, but I think that would warrant a gold badge.

Answer (score 5):

I think at this point Stack Exchange should create a lot of multi/cross-site badges to encourage more participation. This badge looks like a good start. I wouldn't exclude the bounties, just use the normal mortarboard rules and keep it simple.

I'm not sure where they'd show it next to the username, and it might be easier to just have one kind of badge (instead of bronze, silver gold).  This might also work into [the secret badge concept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213130/implement-secret-badges?s=1%7C4.4617) they were thinking of.