# "Generalist" badge for super user & stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

https://superuser.com/badges/15/generalist

I found no user awarded for Generalist Badge.

- What a user should do to achieve this badge?
- Why there isn't any user with these badge?
- How many tags should be active for generalist badge?

Thanks in advance.

Sagar.

Comment: Why did you leave out Server Fault?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>I don't think the generalist badge has been implemented yet: [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/suggested-implementation-for-generalist-badge)</strike>

But time marches on, the codebase grows, the features creep, and now it has been: [details here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/)

Answer (score 12):

They created the badge but as of yet have not actually implemented the rule as far as how to award it.

This is our Duke Nukem Forever of badges.

Comment: It should just be renamed as such for the time being.

Comment: Actually, I'd give the Hacker badge that distinction