# Silver Reversal

Tags: feature-request, badges, reversal-badge

I think that there should be a silver version of the [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) badge.

Because of the extremely high number of votes (20) required, Reversal is  the rarest of al the badges on SO.  ([Except Generalist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26347/generalist-badge-for-super-user-stackoverflow), of course)  On SF, no-one has won it, and on SU, it doesn't exist.  ([Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26919/reversal-badge-not-available-on-super-user))

There are many suitable answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563516/my-application-crashes-with-a-filenotfoundexception-and-i-dont-understand-why/1563668#1563668), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121059/python-for-loop-question/1121778#1121778), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506719/solution-for-writting-a-program-for-keep-secret-photos/506830#506830)) which simply haven't received enough exposure to earn twenty upvotes.

I'm not sure what parameters would be best for a silver version; what do you think?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Because *someone* didn't like the your suggestion.

Comment: Downvoting questions is different on meta, since the score of a question also reflects community support for a feature.  You might think a question is well-worded and valid, but downvote it because you don't think it should be implemented.  That's okay.  Don't take it personally (I didn't DV, btw).

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because someone was trying to get the reversal badge?

Comment: I must have too much blood in my caffeine system - I keep reading the title as *silly* reversal...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps -5 with an answer of +5 or +10 (Bronze), +10 or +15 (Silver), and +20 (Gold). If someone could write a query on StackQL to see how many Bronze and Silver Reversal badges with my criteria would be given out, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Since **Reversal** and **Populist** are the rarest gems of the badge array, why do you want to dilute them with cruddy silver and bronzed knock-offs?

Hand out cubic zirconias to those who just don't have enough of whatever it takes to ring and rock out the bling with diamonds?

Everybody's a winner right? No, not everyone can be.

And that's what makes those badges super duper special.

Comment: Actually, there are way more populists than pundits. On SO right now, there are 19 Reversals, 20 Pundits, and 182 Populists.

Comment: Populists sure get around.

Comment: @mmyers: I meant Generalist (the unimplemented badge), not Populist. @random: I don't think that having lesser versions of a badge detracts from its mystique.  Is Great Question (93 on SO) lessened by the existence of Good Question (1098)?

Comment: Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer badges are your building blocks. Reversal is your personal learjet. It's special by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Well the obvious criteria are +10 votes on an answer to a -3 question, though I'm not 100% sure about the number of down-votes on the question.

I think it needs to be at least -3 for the badge to mean something.

Comment: I would say at least -4, but I'm not sure.