# Badge suggestion: Wide Spread

Tags: discussion, badge-request, reversal-badge

This is a suggestion for a silver version of the "Reversal" badge:

> **Reversal Badge**
>
> Provided answer of +20 score to a
> question of -5 score

I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27862/silver-reversal) and this [good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27862/silver-reversal/27883#27883), but I still feel that this concrete proposal is worth suggesting.

> **Wide Spread Badge**
>
> Provided an answer with more than +2 score
> to a question with less than -2 score
> with a total difference of more than 10.

For example, if the answer score is +7 and the question score is -4, then the Wide Spread badge gets awarded.

Comment: What is the difference between this proposal, and the other one? Could you describe them in your proposal?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I am suggesting a specific rule for a new badge that captures the essence of the Reversal badge but with slightly less stringent criteria. The previous post simply asked for a silver version without suggesting what it should be.