# Badges - Explanation

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I do not understand some of the details regarding Badges. I am not saying that the site has not given proper details - just that I couldn't understand them, and would like to know what they do.

The reason behind this is "Explanation of each badges are given in one line."

Almost all are very clearly explained. But people like me who know less English - might not understand the exact meaning of the badge.

Ok - now the question. I have listed the Badges I don't understand, including the descriptive sentence for reference (original at https://stackoverflow.com/badges).

- **Disciplined - Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher.** (I am confused here. Why would someone delete the post when it has 3 or more upvotes on it? A post with more then 3 upvotes might include some good details / be a good question. Why remove/delete it from stackoverflow?)
- **Epic - Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days.** (My bad English - I couldn't understand this sentence.)
- **Generalist - Active in many different tags** (But how many different tags? Oops! Sorry. I forgot my question ["Generalist" badge for super user & stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26347). I believe it is not in use now.)
- **Beta - Actively participated in the Stack Overflow private beta** 
  (Where is this private Stack overflow site? - I also want to actively participate.)
- **Mortarboard - Hit the daily reputation cap for the first time** (What does this mean - "Hit the daily reputation cap?")
- **Populist - Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with 10 votes by 2x** 
  (I couldn't understand the exact meaning of "votes by 2x".)
- **Reversal - Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score** 
  (Does this mean - Question is bad, answer is good?)
- **Yearling - Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation** 
  (Does this mean, to achieve this Badge, we must be active members and within that year we must gain +200 reputation - is it something like this?)

I know - many people may not like my question, and might hate this kind of question.
But I am confused and I would like clarification, so, I have asked the question here.

Thanks in advance for sharing your great knowledge.

Sagar

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question. You don't need to keep apologizing over and over. Just say what you're trying to say, as clearly as you can, and try to avoid unnecessary punctuation, such as "??????"

Comment: You might be interested in this ==> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#id382403

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Epic - Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days ( Oh ! sorry. My bad English. I couldn't understand this sentence. )
>
> Mortarboard - Hit the daily reputation cap for the first time ( What does this mean - Hit the daily reputation cap ?? - )

You can only earn up to 200 reputation points in one day. If you do something that would normally earn you more than that, you don't get the points. The reason for this is to encourage you not to just spend all your time on Stack Overflow trying to gain more reputation. If you get 200 points on one day, that's known as "hitting the reputation cap."

> Beta - Actively participated in the Stack Overflow private beta ( Where is this private Stack overflow site? - I also want to actively participate )

When Stack Overflow was first starting out, it was being "beta tested." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_testing#Beta_testing That testing is over now, so if you don't already have this badge, you can't get it. :-(

> Yearling - Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation ( Means - to achieve this Badge - We must be active member & within that year we must gain +200 reputations - Is it something like this?? )

Exactly. They don't want you to earn this badge by simply creating an account, and then waiting for a year doing nothing. That's why the reputation requirement is included.

Comment: Do you need to earn the 200 rep within that one year or is it enough to get 200 at some point after being a member for a year? And does 'a year' mean the very first 12 months or the last (sliding window of) 12 months?

Comment: @Jawa I don't know. I think this warrants a separate question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works

Answer (score 8):

Disciplined - This is to reward someone who found a duplicate or some other reason that his question was not appropriate, and decided to delete his question despite it getting him reputation.

Epic - Very Simple. Get to 200 Reputation a day for 50 days.

Generalist - Not Currently Active

Beta - Not Active Anymore (This was for when StackOverflow.com was in Beta, it is no longer in Beta, and you can't get the badge)

Mortarboard - Get to 200 reputation in 1 day. The **Reputation Cap**, as many people call it, is when you hit a point where you cannot get any more reputation from up votes, and must wait till the next day in order to receive reputation for upvotes. For StackOverflow, that cap is at 200 reputation.

Populist - If the accepted answer for a question is 15, you have to get 30. It is double the accepted answers score (minimum of 20)

Reversal - This is for if someone had a bad question, but you still were able to provide a great answer to it. If the question was hard to understand, yet you did and were able to answer it, you could get this badge

Yearling - Yes

Answer (score 3):

> Disciplined - Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher.

It happens that the community upvotes an answer that is wrong. If you are *disciplined*, and it becomes clear that the answer is wrong (after a discussion in the comments, for example), you should delete your answer.