# Details on how the Yearling badge works

Tags: discussion, badges, yearling-badge

Jawa asked me this [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42258/badges-explanation/42262#42262) and I didn't know the answer. So I present it to the meta SO community:

> [To get the Yearling badge] Do you need to earn the 200 rep within that one year or is it enough to get 200 at some point after being a member for a year? And does 'a year' mean the very first 12 months or the last (sliding window of) 12 months?

I would assume that if you hit 200 reputation after you've already been around for a year, then you would get the Yearling badge. But I don't know.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's pretty (maybe too?) simple. You'll get the yearling badge as long as you have at least (Years * 200) rep by the target date.

We don't actually test that you got the reputation within the specified year.

Comment: I see I'm going to have to start participating on Server Fault if I ever want more than one of these badges over there.

Comment: Suppose in 1st year I have reputation under 200 and in 2nd year I have reputation under 400 but more than 200 then will I get Yearling badge in 2nd year?

Comment: @Som Yes, sure :)

Comment: I can confirm this. I have been an inactive member with 1 reputation for 2 years. I recently started participating and I received 2 Yearling badges this week: one when I exceeded 200 reputation, and the other when I exceeded 400.

Comment: Can double confirm this. Received it 4x in the last year: https://i.imgur.com/ma3ywdq.png

Comment: I got it 4x in the last 2 weeks... I think the formula is `yearling count = max(account age in years, rep/200)` (that gives your number of yearling badges *at any given time*, not how many you gain every year)

Comment: If you substitute `min` for `max` in @hugo s formula, you get the right formula. So `yearling count = min(account age in years, rep/200)`. So you can't earn more yearling badges than years you have had an account. Jon Skeet has 10 yearling badges for example.