# Should I have earned the Yearling badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, yearling-badge

I'm not 100% certain but I think that I should have been awarded the yearling badge. Am I missing something?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/66716/peter-mourfield

Thanks!

Comment: @Peter btw there's a tiniest typo in your profile ("I leads").

Comment: Aww.... désolé.

Comment: @Ether about what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jeff's explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works/43244#43244) how the yearling badge is implemented:

> You'll get the yearling badge as long as you have at least (Years * 200) rep by the target date.

Since the target date was February 15, and on that day you didn't have 200 rep yet, I understand this to mean that you'll have to wait until next year.

**Edit:** As Aarobot notes, "target date" may also be any other day; not just one day per year. In that case, you just need a couple more upvotes, so you're above (approx.) 1.2 * 200.

If this is the case, I'd be curious when exactly the badge will be awarded for the second (and third and fourth…) time.

Comment: STACK OVERFLOW FUN FACT: If Jon Skeet walked off the edge of the Earth today, and the status quo was maintained otherwise, he would continue to earn Yearling badges for 857 years.  This is, of course, assuming for the sake of argument that such an event would stop him from interacting with SO.

Comment: I don't think he has to wait an entire year, does he?  My understanding is that you just need to have earned at least 200 rep within a year-long period on any given day, since the badge calculation happens every day.  See this Yearling for today: http://stackoverflow.com/users/42473/mark-booth - member since 2008-12-02, but just got above 200 rep today, and was awarded the badge.  Based on that, Peter will probably get the badge tomorrow, whenever that particular badge check is run.

Comment: @Aarobot: Well, not tomorrow, unless he gets some upvotes until then. Since he's been a member for about 1.2 years, he needs 240 rep by now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Then why do I *HAVE* yearling then? 

Even with all my IDs, I only have 150 rep.

http://stackoverflow.com/users/9169/eli

Comment: @Eli: You probably *did* have more than 200 rep on SO before the [Great Recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010), and received the badge before that. The vote counts on your questions and your SO age support this assumption. So, while you're technically not eligible to receive (or to have received) that badge, badges don't get revoked, and thus you still have it.