# Badge suggestion: Badge for being active member for 3 or 5 years

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Today we have a silver badge (Yearling) for a user who is active for over a year and who has at least 200 reputation. On similar lines, can we have a gold badge for active users for 3 or 5 years who have at least 500 or 1000 reputation.

To summarize my thoughts, I would suggest a gold badge for any one of these options-

1. Gold badge for active user from 3 years and reputation > 500
2. Gold badge for active user from 5 years and reputation > 1000

I cant think of a suitable badge name for this yet. Any thoughts on name of badge is also appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

If it wasn't for the fact that you get a Yearling badge for each year you're a member* I'd vote this up.

* The rule is `if (reputation > number_of_years * 200)` so you can get nothing the first year and then 2 badges the second.

Comment: @ChrisF - Oh, I wasn't aware of the fact that `yearling` can be awarded multiple times to same person. However, it does not turn into a gold badge right?

Comment: @Sachin - it stays silver, but if you're a member for 5 years with more than 1000 reputation you'll have `Yearling` * 5 in your profile.

Comment: @ChrisF - I was hoping somehow if users can get Gold badge for long time active users..;)

Comment: Here's [the source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48118/should-i-have-earned-the-yearling-badge/48119#48119); note my comment underneath it. Of course, at this point, the number is nearing one and a half millenia.

Comment: @Popular Demand - Actually sorry, funny but I somehow understood what you meant with your FunFact. I am deleting my previous two comments. I understood it is making no sense now. Basically you meant even if Job is not an active user for next 4 or many years, even then he will continue to earn yearling badge right?

Comment: @Sachin, yep, that's it!

Comment: @Popular Demand - My only thing in feature request would be for a Gold badge rather than same silver badge every year. GOLD badge is some kind of distinction rather than having 5 silver badges, that is what I am thinking. :)

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't make it dependent on *total* reputation. I'd make it dependent on (say) gaining 1000 reputation in each year of being a member. I don't think they should have to be consecutive years though.

Comment: In true Stack Exchange style, this should require 1000 reputation earned not just in consecutive years, but in consecutive *UTC* years!

Comment: @Grace, hopefully they will factor in leap seconds.

Comment: What about the Leap everything else, @jjnguy?  isn't there leap minute(s) too?  and leap years, there will likely be 2.  and factor in Daylights Saving time just because, but only if they observe it or don't factor it and penalize those who do by making them have to earn an extra hour because that one doesn't exist that they are playing with.

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea: as StackExchange grows older, rewarding people for remaining active since the beginning of time makes sense and should be on the same level as *Fanatic*. Although I would argue the *Yearling* badge should no longer be awarded multiple times in favor of the gold badge.

For the badge name: what about *Veteran* or [*Greybeard*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/greybeard) as the badge name? I'm partial to *Greybeard*, myself.

Comment: Greybeard is not the most woman-friendly badge name you could come up with :-)

Comment: @Kate: Depends on the woman. :-)

Comment: We could give the user the option to rename it "Crone" :)