# Can we have a gold Lustrum badge in the same category as the Yearling badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I saw there was a similar request few years ago ([Badge suggestion: Badge for being active member for 3 or 5 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83717/badge-suggestion-badge-for-being-active-member-for-3-or-5-years)) and I didn't know how to bring that forward again.

I think is just natural extension to have a gold badge that rewards long time commitment much like the silver `Yearling` badge does.

**Lustrum badge will be given to people that have over 5 consecutive `Yearling` badges and have an overall score over 3k** (or 5k or 10k the best amount could be decided here). In any case the score should be higher than the 1k that is necessary for the 5 consecutive `Yearling` badges.

The badge could look like this:

[image: proposed badge]

I went for the word "lustrum" since I think it sounds good (at least better than [semidecadian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196659/any-thoughts-on-a-semidecadian-badge-for-people-with-five-years-service-and-an-a) or quinquennium) and represent 5 years in one word.

[image: dictionary definition of lustrum]

Also **this could be awarded multiple times** much like `Yearling`, thus in 2018 there could be people that have two `Lustrum`  badges.

To a suggestion in the comments this question was copied as an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274392/192821)

Comment: More badges! Give me more badges! :)

Comment: Although I like your request, it is actually a duplicate. You could add a bounty to give attention to it...

Comment: @PatrickHofman I  have a bit different requirement than that and I have a name for the badge :) and I thought a different question would do.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards then name is different and he doesn't propose the 5 consecutive yearlings

Comment: If a change in name is enough to differentiate between badge proposals then I give up. I don't see how 2 almost identical proposals is of benefit to anyone. This question should be an answer to the other. The community is going to decide at the end of the day anyway. If no one agrees with me then that's fine and your question will remain open.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Fundamentally you are right, also Patrick is right should have used a bounty to give attention to the other question. I really don't know  the people will decide and I will respect that decission.

Comment: You also could have answered the other question with your suggestion of a better name... Answers on feature requests can be support or further information.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu please do add an answer to that question so we can upvote it!

Comment: @KateGregory Done http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274392/192821, Thanks