# Badge suggestion: Can we get a "Decade" badge for being an active member for 10 years?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

We have the silver "[yearling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling)" badge. How about a gold badge for old timers who've been an active member for 10 years?

It could be contingent on getting X reputation over the past decade.

Related: [Badge suggestion: Badge for being active member for 3 or 5 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83717/badge-suggestion-badge-for-being-active-member-for-3-or-5-years)

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea to me; unlike the Beta badge ([which no one will ever earn again on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta)) this'd be something that those slackers who waited around until '09 to join the network could look forward to.

Comment: [5 year proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196659/179419), from 5 years ago, apparently it's that time again!

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I asked the question 20 days too early. Had I waited, it would have been exactly 5 years ago :)

Comment: We'll need to nail down the name and _exact_ criteria, but we have to do this, it's a moral imperative! :)

Comment: If we call it a *decayed* badge I might support it ...

Comment: @Tim how about: "Part Of The Furniture"? :)

Comment: my vote goes to "Old Fart" name for this badge

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not an (exact) spec, but laying out a few notes to help:

- Count this by the # of yearling badges awarded, that allows someone to take a break without resetting the counter completely. Doesn't *have* to be *consecutive* years.
- 'Decadian' isn't a word (there's no formal salutation I can find for something that turns 10), but I think we need to make this a gold badge that describes something that gets better with *age*. Cheese comes to mind, but some folks don't care for animal products in their bling, wine has alcohol, as does fruitcake. Hmmm....
- 'Decadated' is a play on *dedicated*, but not sure if that's too cheesy (or cheesy *enough* (see previous point))

There's also something we could conceivably open up to someone that has *ten years* of active experience on the site (while a padded room is appropriate, this would need to be delivered digitally), or maybe we could send someone an award for this. We're open to suggestions.

Anyway, we've got *less* than 6-8 weeks before folks start collecting double-digit yearling badges, so we need to come up with specifics pretty quickly :)

Comment: Maybe they'd appreciate some dedicated swag like a tshirt that reads "I lost 10 years of my life at stack exchange" or "Been at stack exchange for 10 years and got the tshirt" the possibilities are endless!

Comment: There is "centenarian", "nonagenarian", and "octogenarian" so why not "genarian"?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The term is actually "[**denarian**](https://www.medicinenet.com/g00/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=22674&i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%3D&i10c.ua=1&i10c.dv=14)".

Comment: Or, what's wrong with "**double-digits**"?

Comment: I think the criteria sounds good. How about decadeling along the same lines as yearling?

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea, but I think there should be a different name for every year badge earned, it will make it more exciting!