# How is an "active member" defined?

Tags: support, badges, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Details on how the Yearling badge works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I searched meta for this question but couldn't find an answer.

I was wondering how an "**Active member for a year**" **is defined** by the system, as there is the "**Yearling**" **badge** for it.

Am I active when logging in regularly? Or is it also about participating in the community like asking or answering questions, commenting, up- and downvoting...?

Comment: [All you need to qualify for the yearling badge is to earn 200 reputation during that year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works). This is a change from the [earlier requirement of 100 reputation per year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/could-account-association-cheapen-the-yearling-badge).

Comment: Also see: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: Thank you! I think I didn't search for "yearling" or "badge" but for "active member". That's why I couldn't find anything:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“active member” for year is defined as member of community having 200 reputation during that year.

<strike>I think you have to earn 200 reputation in current year if you want to become active member of that year. This badge is awarded yearly from your joining community.(may be because of that name is yearling).</strike>

Update:

You have to earn 200*n reputation to become active member of that year.
i.e.

In 1st year(after 12 months of joining), if you have 200 reputation then you will get Yearling badge.

In 2nd year(after 24 months of joining), if you have 400 reputation then you will get Yearling badge.

So on...

Comment: Does that have to be rep on content created in the year, or just upvotes on what was created years before?

Comment: I think Reputation earned in that year. You are getting upvotes means you have represented community. i.e. You are active member. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ian: No, the algorithm is not that complex, at least not [the last time we heard anything official](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43244/153008). In fact, the "formula" looks more like: `reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200`. See the questions I linked in the comments to the original question for more details.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Suppose in 1st year I have reputation under 200 and in 2nd year I have reputation under 400 but more than 200 then will I get Yearling badge in 2nd year?( As I explained in my update)