# Active - What does that mean?

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Details on how the Yearling badge works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works)

What is an active member? Can a member of this community have a holiday?

Ed? See yealing badge.

e.g. An active member for a year?

Does that mean you post every day for 365 days?

Or

Just looked at the website each of those days

Or

So "

```
Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation
```

"

means that you have to log on every day.

So I get award in 20 days time? i.e. not on the 12th?

>

> ```
> On 10/08/2012 13:02, StackExchange Team wrote:
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Your profile shows that your first day was on August 12th. If you are seeing differently, give it a bit of time. Many badges are awarded by system routines that run periodically so not all badges show up at the exact time they become eligible.
> >
> >  - Stack Exchange Team
> >     Hi,
> >
> >     Just become a member for a year. Why have I not been awarded the yearling badge?
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? It's still August 10 (well, 11th in UTC now, but still not the 12th). You haven't been a member for a full year yet. The account age display on the profile rounds up a bit when displaying the age of the account.

Just wait another day or two and you should get your badge.

Comment: But the summary says I have been a member for a year!

Comment: @EdHeal The display in your profile simply rounds to a more user-friendly wording. Regardless of what it says, your account was created on the 12th. You can get the exact date and time if you mouse over the words "1 year" in your profile.

Comment: So just lie to the user. Either way we are missing a day. (that is 24 hours, or in your language 1 second)