# Is it possible to get the Yearling badge after the first year of registration?

Tags: discussion, yearling-badge

I registered on the StackOverflow 2012-11-17. I did not obviously win the badge during this short period.

**Is it possible to earn this badge otherwise knowing that I am a member for about 6 months and I have more than 600 reputation to this day?**

It's a shame they do not include the period during which the user is registered instead of taking the current year.

Comment: You want to earn the yearling badge based on reputation and not on the amount of time you've been a member?

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match the question.  Are you asking if it is possible to get the badge before you have been a  member for 1 year?

Comment: The question is confusing, but it seems like they assumed the yearling badge was awarded per calendar year, rather than being based on the join date.

Comment: Can I get the Strunk & White badge because I went out and bought my own copy?

Comment: I have been a member for 5 months and have 3k. I don't have the badge.

Comment: Ummmm...no. Time and reputation are not the same, and one cannot be traded for another.

Comment: Actually, I just got mine today after only 358 days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get yearling badge after every complete year you have been a member and `total rep > (numbers of years * 200)`. They are not awarded every first day of January!

So you should get your first yearling on  2013-11-17.

Answer (score 10):

No,

you earn that badge after a year of activity. Not before. That is kind of the deal with a year-ling badge.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the clarification that "year" refers to the number of days since you joined, not a calendar year, I will answer the question in your title. If you got 199 rep in your first year, you would not earn Yearling. But if at the end of your second year you had 400 rep or more, you would get TWO yearling badges. (I have experienced this on sites where I had a small rep for a long time.)

Source: [Details on how the Yearling badge works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43240/details-on-how-the-yearling-badge-works?rq=1)