# When "exactly" is the Yearling badge awarded?

Tags: discussion, reputation, yearling-badge

I just noticed that I've been a member for 1 year and 2+ days. I hovered over the *1 year* text to see the date. I have exactly 200 rep.

I found multiple questions about the Yearling badge not being awarded, but the users hadn't quite reached the 1 year mark yet.

I thought maybe I needed *more than* 200 rep, but the badge description says *at least* 200.

So perhaps the association bonus doesn't count? Or perhaps the description is incorrect and should read *more than* 200. Or perhaps the badges aren't awarded in real time and I have to wait for some scheduled calculation?

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183507/203410) says that rep > 200 is required. However, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202944/203410) says rep >= 200 is required. And [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/203410) says the association bonus *does* count, but rep > 200 is required. A comment on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108705/203410) says the calculation is done nightly.

Just curious. Why haven't I received my Yearling badge for meta? If I need *more than* 200, the description should be corrected. And does that mean I have to wait another whole year?

**Updated**

If we consider the comment by *Sha Wiz Dow Ard* and take the definition of *earn* literally, we didn't *earn* our first rep point. But that is misleading because what about rep that you *earned* and then gave away as a bounty (or lost by other means)? You still *earned* it.

For reference, this is the description at time of writing.

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

It seems that it is calculated on how much you *have* and not how much you *earned*. So you need to *have* rep > 200. And thus, it should be explained that way.

I think the description on the [badge page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and the description in [this wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/203410) should be updated. I know I can edit the answer, but while I now have anecdotal evidence, I am still not exactly sure how the calculation is done behind the scenes.

For reference, the wiki answer has this description at time of writing.

> Have a reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200

Comment: You need to *earn* 200. Since you start with 1, having 200 now means you earned only 199. No badge for you. :(

Comment: Gave you 5 more rep, see if you get your badge now.

Comment: Yeah, you [got it now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=203410)!

Comment: Ah yes... I wasn't thinking about the fact that you start with 1. Good point, but kind of sneaky in the wording. Strange that it's now been awarded since I thought the calculation was only done on the anniversary.

Comment: LOL... My activity tab now reads *asked "When "exactly" is the yearling badge awarded?"* followed immediately by *awarded Yearling*.

Comment: Enjoy - I've updated the wiki answer. Note that it originally used the _greater than_ symbol (`>`), not the _greater than or equal to_ symbol (`≥`) -- the difference is crucial. Assuming `x` is an integer, `x > 200` is the same inequality as `x ≥ 201`, so it is _technically_ correct.

Comment: I'm the one that just changed it from `>=` to `>`. It was indeed `>=` when I quoted it. The quote in my question above is a copy and paste.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like an extreme edge case you just found: you need to *earn* 200, not *have* 200. So having 200 means you earned only 199 thus not yet qualified.

And as mentioned in the [full list of all badges and their description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/152859):

> - If at any point you qualify for this year's badge, you will receive all badges you had previously missed up until this year whenever the script runs again.

The script itself appears to runs every 5 minutes, looking for users who won the badge as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling):

> [image]

Comment: So is the badge revoked if the reputation falls below 201 after the badge is awarded?

Comment: I thought the general rule was that badges don't get revoked unless there's extraordinary circumstances (such as cheating or legal issues)

Comment: @R.J as Dennis said above, it won't be revoked. In this case the OP didn't earn it until having 205 points i.e. gaining 204. Only tag badges are revoked automatically when reputation is changing downwards.

Comment: I missed the part about "If at any point you qualify..." because I already had it in my head that it only happened on the anniversary due to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108705/203410). Apparently, that is how the list page used to read. That same question also has a comment about the script running nightly.

Comment: @toxalot yep, things might have changed in the last couple of years.

Comment: I still think that using the word *earn* makes it misleading. See my updated question.

Comment: I just looked at the yearling page, I see badges awarded as little as 5 minutes apart.

Comment: @toxalot right, my bad! Probably even on Stack Overflow there's not always a winner every 5 minutes. Hopefully 5 minutes will be final and correct answer, however notice we never see user with 200 rep there, only 201 and above which pretty much prove my assumption.