# Better definition of Generalist badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, generalist-badge

Perhaps all I want is to have a "Not yet implemented" indicator on the Generalist badge description, if [How many tags needed to earn the Generalist badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-many-tags-needed-to-earn-the-generalist-badge) is to be believed.

But actually, I'd rather have it defined better and then implemented, such as "Has earned the Nice Answer badge on questions that cover at least 20 tags, can only be awarded once per user", and then have someone (me?) come up with a query to find those people.

No reason why it can't be awarded long after it's been earned, and the logic adjusted so that each user gets checked when they earn a 'Nice Answer' badge.

But at the very least, can't we get the badge description improved?

Rob

Comment: Might want to add a link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/suggested-implementation-for-generalist-badge

Comment: You could always run a query at http://statoverflow.com

Comment: @Brad - eh? Just says 'testing' for me.

Comment: @dmckee - I think you just have! Thanks. (ugh - 30 second rule!)

Comment: And - my point is not "here's how to implement it", but rather "don't leave it in limbo without indicating that it's in limbo"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I prefer, "Our little Duke Nukem Forever," or, "Check back in 6 to 8 weeks."

But, if we have to be professional about it: "Reserved for future badge to reward users active in a variety of tags." Or, better yet, remove it until it's actually activated.

Comment: My biggest issue with the whole thing is...how hard is it to actually implement? I've always been confused about what the actual hangup was concerning it. Was there confusion about how to properly award it, or was it in the checking algorithm or what?

Comment: Yeah - it should be easy to implement. But I guess it's not high priority. But considering questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176011/sql-to-determine-minimum-sequential-days-of-access , I think perhaps the query to work it out wasn't quite known yet. The query for Generalist could just be "select a.userid, COUNT(DISTINCT qt.TagID) from answers a join questiontags qt on a.questionid = qt.questionid where a.votes > 10 group by a.userid;" (or whatever).

Answer (score 5):

We've been wanting that sucker defined and implemented for a while now. The longer it goes, the longer I believe it will just get left by the wayside in favor of the silver and gold individual tag badges.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if they want to make acquiring every single badge close to impossible. That way, no one is perfect.  Though I think they should just add the "OMG PONIES" badge just for you.

Comment: I originally requested a pink OMG PONIES badge way back in April for users who clicked the Cornify button over 1,000 times.

Answer (score 2):

When Generalist was first introduced (not implemented) we didn't have the [tag-based badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags). Now that we do, it would make sense to tie the two together. Generalist could be earned when a user participates in 10 or 20 of the tags that have, in turn, earned their own badge.

Comment: Perhaps Generalist should be a gold badge, to indicate 'Has earned 10 silver tag-based badges'