# Do I have to get 15 score for a single answer per tag to get the generalist badge?

Tags: support, badges, generalist-badge

I read some similar questions, and the comments in them:

- [Does the generalist badge require 15 score total, or 15 score per tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/does-the-generalist-badge-require-15-score-total-or-15-score-per-tag)
- [Better definition of Generalist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14875/better-definition-of-generalist-badge)

Do I have to get a single answer with a score of 15 or better in each category, or could I get a generalist badge in the following scenario?

In the tags ranked 20-40, I have these:

- 30 answers upvoted exactly once, and not downvoted
- 15 answers downvoted exactly once, and not upvoted

(also: does the score apply to questions too?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need one answer with 15 or above net vote count (upvotes minus downvotes), you need a total net vote count above 15 in 20 of the top 40 tags.
<sub>You can look at my profile an Stack Overflow - I have Generalist, but my answers with a total score above 15 don't cover that requirement.</sub>

Only answers count - your tag score doesn't take questions into account. Community Wiki answers don't count either. (You can verify that by hovering over your tag score in your profile's tag page.)

The last requirement is for the site you're on as a whole:

> Only awarded to anyone after each of the 40 top tags has at least 200 questions

Source: [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I found this query helpful to monitor your progress towards Generalist: [Generalist Progression #updated](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1387/generalist-progression-updated)

Comment: The one problem with the Generalist Progression Query is that it gets stale. Stackoverflow.com/tags (for the top 40) and the tags tab on the profile page is updated every day. Merlyn is actually much closer than that query suggests. A total of six more upvotes in non-cw answers (1 vote in Vb.net, 2 in python and 3 in either python, multithreading or visual-studio) and a Merylyn will qualify for the shiny generalist badge.

Comment: Thanks Mat!  @Conrad: Great to hear :)  I've been busting my butt on tags I was lower on (not sure if I was doing it right because I tried to calculate the whole thing by hand), but I wasn't recalculating because I wanted to enjoy getting more familiar with the technologies I had less experience with.